# VS2008 exe-VC6 dll interoperability

Tags: visual-studio-2008, string, visual-c++-6

I heard somewhere that passing of wchar_t across VS2005 and VC6 is quite dangerous.
I tried to delete memory which was allocated from VC6 dll from VS2008 exe, and it raised assertion. After referring [Bad pointer or link issue when creating wstring from vc6 dll](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1175330/bad-pointer-or-link-issue-when-creating-wstring-from-vc6-dll), i added one func in VC6 dll which shall be used to delete memory. And it solved my issue.

But is there any difference between internal sturcture of whcar_t between VS2008 and VC6.. Please help..

Rgrds,
Jinto

Answer (score 1, accepted):

VC6 didn't have a `wchar_t` type, to start with. However, on both it's a 16 bits type, so that shouldn't cause major issues. It's likely unrelated to the problems you have with `malloc()` and `free()`, which work on raw, untyped memory.

Comment: I dont think so, Iam able to use wchar_t inside VC6 apps. [MFC AppWizar exe - console]. 
But as u said no major issues when used with different CRTs.